# Vue.js - Transitions between conditionals (v-if and v-else)

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way that you can use `transition` between vuejs conditionals `v-if` and `v-else`?

As an example:

```
<transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
    <p v-else>Goodbye</p>
</transition>
```

---

```
new Vue({
   el: '#demo',
   data: {
       show: true
   }
})
```

---

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s
 }

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
    opacity: 0
}
```

I can't seem to get a `transition` to work in such a scenario, where, as you toggle `show`, the `<p>` elements use a `transition` between them.

https://jsfiddle.net/fbponh78

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that vue transition does not see the element change, it only sees the content change.

This is caused by the fact that both elements have the same tag name, so vue just reuses this. To counteract this, give both elements an differed key value:

```html
<p key=1 v-if="show">hello</p>
<p key=2 v-else>Goodbye</p>
```

Example:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        show: true
    }
});
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
    <button v-on:click="show = !show">
        Toggle
    </button>
    <transition name="fade">
        <p key=1 v-if="show">hello</p>
        <p key=2 v-else>Goodbye</p>
    </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're lazy you can also set a key on only 1 element, it'll still work.

Comment: Dont forget **transition mode** to prevent Simultaneous entering and leaving like this: `<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">`

Comment: @Ferribig , do you mind explaining this solution? Thanks for all this info btw!

Answer (score 11):

Use two transitions:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="!show">Goodbye</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/saeedahmadi/fbponh78/10/

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem, where a complex component would make `v-else` enter before `v-if` was removed. What helped me was `@Khalil's` (comments) suggestion:

```
<transition mode="out-in" ...
```